# Remove stairs in Dwarf Fortress?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I built a couple of up/down stairs in DF by mistake, how can I remove them?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This depends on how you built the stairs.

If you designated them and a miner constructed them, you can designate the stairs with "Remove Up Stairs/Ramps" <kbd>d</kbd>-<kbd>z</kbd>

If you constructed them in the build menu, you want to designate the stairs with "Remove Construction" <kbd>d</kbd>-<kbd>n</kbd>

Comment: Also worth considering if there is access to both the top and bottom of the stairs. So if there is a path to the bottom of the stairs only (the top doesn't lead anywhere) you'll want to be sure to remove the top first otherwise at best the top will be inaccessible, or at worst the top of the stairs will collapse, falling on your dwarf and causing a small amount of fun.

Comment: That's only if user5781's up/down stairs are built on top of each other, of course. A single constructed up/down stair will only exist on one z-level. A *mined* up/down stair is a little different in that upon removing it, you will still have a downward stair on the original z-level (but the z-level below will still be solid rock).

Comment: BTW, how did you do the "letters"? That is, what is the markdown code for it?

Comment: You surround the key's text with keyboard tags as in: <kbd>X</kbd>

Comment: We really need a shorter syntax for that. :P

Comment: `d-z` does not seem to work for down-only stairs. Is there another option?